# Need help understanding how flutter_bloc injects bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

from what I understand so far, providing a bloc at the runApp method level makes it available in all the application. I'm I wrong?

I have this implementation

My main.dart file

```
void main() => runApp(
      RepositoryProvider<AuthenticationRepository>(
        create: (context) {
          return AuthenticationService();
        },
        child: MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: [
            BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
              create: (context) {
                final authService =
                    RepositoryProvider.of<AuthenticationRepository>(context);
                return AuthenticationBloc(authService)..add(AppLoaded());
              },
            ),
            BlocProvider<SignupBloc>(
              create: (context) {
                final authService =
                    RepositoryProvider.of<AuthenticationRepository>(context);
                return SignupBloc(authService);
              },
            )
          ],
          child: MyApp(),
        ),
      ),
    );

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is AuthenticationSuccess) {
            return MainScreen(user: state.user);
          }
          return LoginScreen();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and then I have this widget:

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:myapp/features/signup/bloc/signup_bloc.dart';
import 'package:myapp/shared/ui/textStyles.dart';
import 'package:myapp/shared/ui/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ProfileInfoForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileInfoFormState createState() => _ProfileInfoFormState();
}

class _ProfileInfoFormState extends State<ProfileInfoForm> {
  String _firstname, _lastname, _city, _country, _gender = "";
  GlobalKey<FormState> _key = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  List<bool> _selections = List.generate(2, (index) => false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _signupBloc = Provider.of<SignupBloc>(context);

    return BlocListener<SignupBloc, SignupState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is CreateAccountFailure) {
          log("message");
        }
      },
      child: BlocBuilder(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is CreateAccountLoading) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Form(
                    key: _key,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 250,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: CustomTextField(
                            hintText: "Firstname",
                            secured: false,
                            onSave: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _firstname = value;
                              });
                            },
                            onValidate: (value) {
                              if (value == "") {
                                return "Please enter your firstname";
                              }
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: CustomTextField(
                            hintText: "Lastname",
                            secured: false,
                            onSave: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _lastname = value;
                              });
                            },
                            onValidate: (value) {
                              if (value == "") {
                                return "Please enter your lastname";
                              }
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Select your gender",
                                  style: blackSubTitle,
                                ),
                              ),
                              ToggleButtons(
                                fillColor: Colors.white,
                                renderBorder: true,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                selectedBorderColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    // decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                                    width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(220),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Female",
                                      style: blackSubTitle,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(220),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Male",
                                      style: blackSubTitle,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                                isSelected: _selections,
                                onPressed: (index) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _selections =
                                        List.generate(2, (index) => false);
                                    _selections[index] = !_selections[index];

                                    if (_selections.elementAt(0) == true) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        _gender = "Female";
                                      });
                                    }
                                    if (_selections.elementAt(1) == true) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        _gender = "Male";
                                      });
                                    }
                                  });
                                },
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
                                _key.currentState.save();
                                // _signupBloc.add(
                                //   InitProfilePressed(
                                //       firstname: _firstname,
                                //       lastname: _lastname,
                                //       gender: _gender),
                                // );
                              } else {}
                            },
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    width: 200,
                                    height: 60,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Continue",
                                      style: whiteSubTitle,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

> ```
>     BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type Bloc<dynamic, dynamic>.
>
>     No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to BlocProvider.of<Bloc<dynamic, dynamic>>().
>
>     This can happen if the context you used comes from a widget above the BlocProvider.
>
>     The context used was: BlocBuilder<Bloc<dynamic, dynamic>, dynamic>(dirty, state: _BlocBuilderBaseState<Bloc<dynamic, dynamic>,
> ```
>
> dynamic>#a73f5(lifecycle state: created))
>
> BlocProvider.of<Bloc<dynamic, dynamic>>().
> This can happen if the context you used comes from a widget above the BlocProvider.
> The context used was: BlocBuilder<Bloc<dynamic, dynamic>, dynamic>(dirty, state:
> _BlocBuilderBaseState<Bloc<dynamic, dynamic>, dynamic>#a73f5(lifecycle state: created)) The relevant error-causing widget was:
> BlocListener<SignupBloc, SignupState>
>
> #23     ComponentElement.performRebuild  package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4571
> #24     StatefulElement.performRebuild  package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4719
> #25     Element.rebuild  package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4262
> #26     BuildOwner.buildScope  package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2667
> #27     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame  package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:866
> #28     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback  package:flutter/…/rendering/binding.dart:286
> #29     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback  package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1115
> #30     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame  package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1054
> #31     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame  package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:970
> #35     _invoke  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:269:10)
> #36     _drawFrame  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:227:3) (elided 3 frames from dart:async)

What I'm I missing?

thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it all right except one thing

You missed types for BlocBuilder

```
child: BlocBuilder<SignupBloc, SignupState>(
```

Also you can use `BlocConsumer` which includes `BlocListener` & `BlocBuilder` functionality

```
    return BlocConsumer<SignupBloc, SignupState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is CreateAccountFailure) {
          log("message");
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is CreateAccountLoading) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
```